# Record-view library doesn't work normally in android

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

I am using the latest version of Record-view library `(compile 'com.devlomi.record-view:record-view:2.0.1')`. I want to use it in a dialog view. When I use library codes in the activity everything works fine but in dialog view when I touch and hold the record button it acts like I tap it. I mean touch and release record button happens immediately! the code below is my dialog XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_margin="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_dialog"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <com.alexina.counselor.CustomViews.mTextView
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_clock"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorMedium"
                android:id="@+id/input_time"
                android:text="@string/time"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/input_cost"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_mic_btn"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/tejarat"
                android:id="@+id/input_logo"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp" />


            <com.alexina.counselor.CustomViews.mTextViewBold
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_credit_card"
                android:id="@+id/input_cost"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:paddingRight="24dp"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorLight"
                android:text="120000"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/input_logo"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/input_cost"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/input_category"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.github.florent37.expansionpanel.ExpansionHeader
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:expansion_headerIndicator="@+id/headerIndicator"
                    app:expansion_layout="@+id/expansionLayout"
                    app:expansion_toggleOnClick="true">


                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView

                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:id="@+id/headerIndicator"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_expand_button" />

                    <com.alexina.counselor.CustomViews.mTextView
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                        android:text="@string/category"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/textColorMedium"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                </com.github.florent37.expansionpanel.ExpansionHeader>

                <com.github.florent37.expansionpanel.ExpansionLayout
                    android:id="@+id/expansionLayout"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent">


                    <segmented_control.widget.custom.android.com.segmentedcontrol.SegmentedControl

                        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:id="@+id/segmented_control"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:radiusForEverySegment="true"
                        app:columnCount="4"
                        app:distributeEvenly="false"
                        app:radius="14dp"
                        app:textVerticalPadding="4dp"
                        app:strokeWidth="0.5dp"
                        app:segmentVerticalMargin="2dp"
                        app:segmentHorizontalMargin="2dp"
                        app:unSelectedStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        app:selectedTextColor="@color/textColorLight"
                        app:selectedStrokeColor="@color/toast"
                        app:selectedBackgroundColor="@color/toast"/>

                </com.github.florent37.expansionpanel.ExpansionLayout>


            </LinearLayout>



            <ImageView
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/map"
                android:id="@+id/input_map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/input_category" />

            <ImageView
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_mic_btn"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"
                android:id="@+id/input_map_refresh"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/input_category"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <com.alexina.counselor.CustomViews.mTextView
                android:paddingRight="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                android:textColor="@color/tik"
                android:id="@+id/input_address"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/input_map"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/input_address"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <com.devlomi.record_view.RecordView
                    android:id="@+id/record_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/record_button"
                    app:slide_to_cancel_arrow="@drawable/recv_ic_arrow"
                    app:slide_to_cancel_arrow_color="#000000"
                    app:slide_to_cancel_bounds="8dp"
                    app:slide_to_cancel_margin_right="10dp"
                    app:slide_to_cancel_text="Slide To Cancel"
                    app:counter_time_color="#ff0000"
                    />

                <com.devlomi.record_view.RecordButton
                    android:id="@+id/record_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/recv_bg_mic"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    app:mic_icon="@drawable/recv_ic_mic_white" />


            </RelativeLayout>


            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_black_24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_mic_btn"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/input_map_refresh"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="11dp" />

            <com.alexina.counselor.CustomViews.mEdittext
                android:id="@+id/input_description"
                android:background="@drawable/background_edittext"
                android:hint="@string/explanation"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="8sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorMedium"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:gravity="top|right"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorLight"
                android:layout_below="@+id/input_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="72sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/input_description"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.alexina.counselor.CustomViews.mButton
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_cancel_btn"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorMedium"
                    android:text="@string/cancel"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_dialog_btn_solid_neg"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <com.alexina.counselor.CustomViews.mButton
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_approve_btn"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorLight"
                    android:text="@string/save"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_dialog_btn_solid_pos"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

and my Java code is:

```
public static void popUpDialogInput(final Context context, List<String> categories, int layout,
                                        View.OnClickListener approveClick, View.OnClickListener cancelClick){

        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(layout);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Button ok = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_approve_btn);
        Button cancel = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel_btn);
        ok.setOnClickListener(approveClick);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(cancelClick);

        RecordView recordView = (RecordView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.record_view);
        RecordButton recordButton = (RecordButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.record_button);
        //IMPORTANT
        recordButton.setRecordView(recordView);
        recordView.setSlideToCancelText(context.getString(R.string.say_sth));
        recordView.setOnRecordListener(new OnRecordListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                //Start Recording..
                Log.d("RecordView", "onStart");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                //On Swipe To Cancel
                Log.d("RecordView", "onCancel");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish(long recordTime) {
                //Stop Recording..    
            }

            @Override
            public void onLessThanSecond() {
                //When the record time is less than One Second
                Log.d("RecordView", "onLessThanSecond");
            }
        });

        final SegmentedControl segmentedControl = (SegmentedControl) dialog.findViewById(R.id.segmented_control);
        segmentedControl.addSegments(categories);
        segmentedControl.setAdapter(new AdapterAppSegment());
        segmentedControl.addOnSegmentSelectListener(new OnSegmentSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSegmentSelected(SegmentViewHolder segmentViewHolder, boolean b, boolean b1) {
                Log.d("ALEXINA", "onSegmentSelected");
            }
        });

        segmentedControl.addOnSegmentClickListener(new OnSegmentClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSegmentClick(SegmentViewHolder segmentViewHolder) {
                Log.d("ALEXINA", "onSegmentClick");

            }
        });

        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();
    }
```